# python intra-module import breaks when used as submodule

Tags: python, import

I have a fairly simple python package. When used on it's own, it seems to work fine. It looks something like this:

```
my_script/
    __init__.py
    my_script.py
    my_script_helper.py
    data/
        my_data.csv
```

__init__.py is blank.

my_script.py looks something like this:

```
from my_script_helper import *

def do_thing(x):
    return helper(x)
```

my_script_helper.py looks something like this:

```
def helper(y):
    return y + 1
```

I can run a test script that imports my_script.py and get the expected output. As far as I can tell, using the my_script package on its own works fine. So, I stick everything into a repository on GitHub and import it into another project as a submodule.

The other project now looks something like this:

```
my_big_project/
    my_script/
        __init__.py
        my_script.py
        my_script_helper.py
        data/
            my_data.csv
    my_big_project.py
```

However, now the import statement in my_script.py gives me an unresolved reference error. If I go into my_script.py and change the import statement to the following:

```
from my_script.my_script_helper import *
```

then it works. Of course, that statement breaks the package when on its own. And I assume I probably shouldn't be poking around in submodules like that.

I'm very much a python and programming in general newbie and struggle with import, namespace, and __init__ stuff. If someone could be so kind as to point me in the right direction as to how I should structure my imports here I would be grateful.

EDIT:
After much banging my head against the wall, the solution I found that worked was to add the following to my_script.py:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'my_script'))
```

I feel like this probably isn't the correct way to do it, but it's been working fine so far. This is for python 3.6.1, in case anyone stumbles in here.

Answer (score 0):

Because initially the package is independent and it worked fine for you. And now you have used the package inside another project you should use absolute path and this is the reason you are getting the issue.